Sequence $\{a_n\}$ where $a_n$ is the smallest proper multiple of $a_{n-1}$ containing $a_{n-2}$ in its digits
Recently, I've been interested in sequences $\{a_n\}$ where $a_n$ is the smallest proper multiple (multiple of a number larger than itself) of $a_{n-1}$ containing $a_{n-2}$ in its digits. A number $Y$ is said to be containing $X$ in its digits if one can obtain $X$ by removing zero or more digits from $Y$.
What I'm really interested in is the behavior of the sequence under different starting values. With $a_1 = 1$ and $a_2 = 1$, the sequence is just the power of tens. With $a_1 = 1$ and $a_2 = 2$, the sequence goes
$$1, 2, 10, 20, 100, 200, 1000, 2000, ...$$
With $a_1 = 2$ and $a_2 = 2$, the sequence goes
$$2, 2, 12, 24, 120, 240, 1200, ...$$
So far, $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ remains bounded as $n \rightarrow \infty$. With $a_1=1$ and $a_2 = 3$ (see OEIS sequence A372880.), something different happens, the sequence goes:
$$1, 3, 12, 36, 612, 1836, 168912, 10810368, 16366897152, 51703028103168, 1563447866811697152,...$$
And the ratio between the consecutive sequence members goes:
$$3, 4, 3, 17, 3, 92, 64, 1514, 3159, 30239, 15043784, 49130515,...$$
It seems to me that $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \rightarrow \infty$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$.
Main Question: Can anyone prove/disprove that the ratio does diverge for the starting values $(1, 3)$?
Another conjecture: For any valid starting value, the ratio is either:

eventually becomes $10$ (example: $(1, 1)$ as starting values.)

bouncing between $2$ and $5$ (example $(1, 2)$ or $(2, 2)$ as starting values.)

diverge to $\infty$. (the starting values $(1, 3)$ is expected to fall in this category)



By the way, there's a terminology issue on my side here. I thought the term proper multiple could be used to describe multiples larger than itself, analogous to proper divisors. ‍♂️ Are there any better ways to phrase my question?

I think "proper multiple" is perfectly understandable, especially given that you have elaborated what you mean by it. I'm not sure if it is standard terminology (it should be), but who cares!

Heuristically , the ratio should diverge in the case $(1,3)$ because it will become more and more difficult to find a suitable multiple containing larger and larger substrings , but I have no concrete idea yet for a proof.
